# clause, who something is

Tags: clauses

[image]

I find this sentence,

> It is evident who the real murderer is.

I feel it a little awkward. Is it grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is correct.

It means "(Who the real murderer is) is evident."

The "It" refers to the clause "who the real murderer is".